# django query to get posts from users followed by a user

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My models:

```
class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='client_profile')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
    related_name='follows',blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField( blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."
    )
    mobile_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
    max_length=17, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now = False, null = True)
    profile_summary = models.TextField()
    my_career_objective = models.TextField()
    educational_qualification = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    work_experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    skill_set = models.TextField(blank=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    # new fileds
    about_me = models.TextField(blank=True)
    birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    lives_in = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,max_length=150, blank=True)
    marital_status = models.CharField(choices=MARITAL_CHOICES,max_length=150, blank=True,default=1)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    political_incline = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # other_social_networks = models.TextField(blank=True)
    hobbies = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_tv_shows = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_movies = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_games = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_music_band_artists = models.TextField("Favorite Music, Bands / Artists", blank=True)
    favorite_books = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_writers = models.TextField(blank=True)
    other_interests = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subscription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="Free")


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + " " + str(self.user.last_name)




class Task(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    datestamp = models.DateField( auto_now=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes',blank=True)
    is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('student:dashboard')
   objects = PostManager()

   @property
   def comments(self):
       instance = self
       qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
       return qs

   @property
   def get_content_type(self):
       instance = self
       content_type = 
       ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
       return content_type
```

I want to display all tasks from logged in user and also all the tasks from all users followed by logged in user.What is the best django query to implement this? the follows field in the ClientProfile model is given as many to many field to depict all users followed by the user.How to write django query with 'or'.Each task points to a user through foreign key 'student' . I want to display all tasks from logged in user and all users followed by logged in user in the homepage

Comment: Have you tried any queries? What were the results? Post them with outputs.

Comment: task = Task.objects.filter(Q(student=request.user) | Q(student__in=request.user.client_profile.follows)).order_by('timestamp').prefetch_related('images_set')......Thhis doesnt work ..ERROR:'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
@Aravind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a related_name attribute in `student` field of Task. (let's call it `task`)
If logged_in_user is your logged in user object then `logged_in_user.task` would give task of logged_in_user and for user's followers tasks:

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(student__in= logged_in_user.follows.all())
```

Without related_name.

```
task = Task.objects.filter(Q(student=logged_in_user) | Q(student__in=logged_in_user.follows.all()))
```

Comment: I have tried this query: client=ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    task = Task.objects.filter(Q(student=request.user) | Q(student__in=client.follows.all()).order_by('timestamp').prefetch_related('images_set')

Comment: @MohitHarshan `client.follows.all()` you have missed brackets.

Comment: @MohitHarshan If it helps, mark this as `answered`. It's still showing in unanswered category.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
 client=ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
 task = Task.objects.filter
  (Q(student=request.user) | 
   Q(student__in=client.follows.all()))
 .order_by('timestamp').prefetch_related('images_set')
```